canvas.toDataURL with webp not working on iPad Chrome and Safari
I am trying to manipulate images via javascript using canvas.toDataURL('image/webp', 0.8); but although it works on Android and Windows it does not work on IOS (iPad) which returns a png instead.
Same goes for canvas.toBlob()
I am using Safari 16.6 and Chrome 130.0 on the ipad
https://jsfiddle.net/gdp70xsf/


function doConvert() {
  const fileInput = document.querySelector("input[type='file']");
  const img = document.querySelector("img");
  const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  const p = document.querySelector("p");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  const file = fileInput.files[0];

  if (file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      const imgElement = new Image();
      imgElement.src = e.target.result;

      imgElement.onload = function() {
        // Set up the canvas size
        const width = imgElement.width;
        const height = imgElement.height;
        const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

        canvas.width = width * dpr;
        canvas.height = height * dpr;

        // Apply scaling and draw image onto canvas
        ctx.scale(dpr, dpr);
        ctx.drawImage(imgElement, 0, 0, width, height);

        // Convert to WebP and display in the img element
        let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/webp", 0.8);
        img.src = dataUrl;

        p.innerHTML = navigator.userAgent+'<HR>'+dataUrl.substring(0,30)+'...'; // Logging the base64 string for reference
      };
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
</script>
img, canvas {
  width:auto;
  height:50vh;
  vertical-align:top;  
}
canvas {
  border:solid 1px orange;
}
img {
  border:solid 1px red;  
}
div {
  margin:10px;
}
<input type="file" onChange="doConvert()" />
<div>canvas:<canvas></canvas> img:<img /></div>
<div>
  <p></p>
</div>



Is there a way around this (I need to place a canvas manipulated image back into an <img> as a webp on any device type - including the Apple ones)?


These restrictions are all real for iOS : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15

For devices with less than 256 MB of RAM, the maximum size for decoded GIF, PNG, and TIFF images is 3 megapixels; for devices with more or equal to 256 MB of RAM, the maximum size is 5 megapixels.

Canvas elements have a maximum size of 3 megapixels for devices with less than 256 MB of RAM and 5 megapixels for devices with 256 MB or more RAM.
Each top-level entry point's JavaScript execution time is restricted to 10 seconds.

If you try to render or read a 6MB image, you will receive a malformed blob/dataURL string, and so on, because these limits don't throw any problems. And you'll be correct when you believe that the File API and the canvas methods toDataURL and toBlob are faulty. However, this is a system limitation and not a browser problem.

As a result, the JavaScript API displays incorrect functionality.

More information for this can be found on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL


